# Meaning of relay acronyms: H-LP, E/G, DIM etc

Tags: toyota, relay, fuse-panel

I'm trying to get to know my fuse and relay boxes better. They're labelled, but the labels are mostly acronyms and shorthand, and googling any particular acronym gives a lot of mentions of common tasks on forums but not any definitions or explanations (at least not that I can find).

I think it's probably easier to ask them all together and create a definitive go-to guide than have over a dozen questions which for an expert are absurdly easy with potentially one word answers. Maybe a great answer could help a novice like me understand how the different items interrelate. Note that StackExchange policy on "list questions" are that they're okay if they're clearly bounded and finite, like this, it's never-ending lists with an unlimited number of possibilities that are "too broad".

These are specific to my 1998 Toyota RAV4, but it'd be good to have a definitive universal resource, so please comment and/or feel free to include in answers any common ones for other makes that are missing.

### Relays

- E/G Main
- H-LP
- ST (I suspect this controls the starter motor but could be wrong)
- EFI (95% sure this is "Engine Fuel Injection")
- MG/C
- DIM

Fuse acronyms are all detailed in the owner's guide, which for this model is available online, but **relays are not detailed in the owner's guide at all**.

Comment: h-lp would be headlamps, efi is as you say or electronic fuel injection, mg/c is for the air conditioning compressor magnetic clutch, st is for starter.

Comment: Never seen these things in user guides. Service guides - maybe. On Volvos DIM is the Driver Information Module, aka the instrument panel, aka dashboard. Could also be the for the headlight dimmer switch.

Comment: @Ben, please answer questions with an answer.  Just because you don't know all of them doesn't mean it isn't a good answer.

Comment: And I thought Egyptian hieroglyphics were hard....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Legend to Codes**

E/G - Main is the relay for the Radiator fans.

EFI - Is the electronic fuel injection relay.

DIM - is the headlight dimmer relay.

H-LP - is the headlamp relay.

MG/C - is the air conditioning compressor magnetic clutch relay.

ST - is the starter relay.